# Insert and subselect

Tags: sql, db2

```
INSERT INTO S654321.PERSON
(PNR, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME)
VALUES
SELECT 32, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
FROM S654321.CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTNR = 'C002'
```

Returns sqlcode -104 and sqlstate 42601. Do you see the error?
The select statement itself is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is that when you insert records you either use a select, or you specify the values.  You don't do both.  This is ok

```
insert into table
(field1)
values
(value1)
```

as is this:

```
insert into table
(field1)
select distinct value1
from somewhere
```

So pick a method.

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing two statements, this is what you should do

```
INSERT INTO S654321.PERSON
(PNR, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME)
SELECT 32, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
FROM S654321.CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTNR = 'C002'
```