# sql statement to select and insert one value from one table rest from outside the tables

Tags: insert, db2

I have two db2 tables, table one contains rows of constant data with id as one of the columns. second table contains id column which is foreign key to id column in first table and has 3 more varchar columns.

I am trying to insert rows into second table, where entry into id col is based on a where clause and the remaining columns get values from outside.

```
table1 has columns id, t1c1, t1c2, t1c3
table2 has columns id, t2c1, t2c2, t2c3
```

to insert into table2, I am trying this query:

```
insert into table2 values 
(select id from table1 where t1c2 like 'xxx', 'abc1','abc2');
```

I know it is something basic I am missing here. 
Please help correcting this query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert and subselect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043818/insert-and-subselect)

Comment: example data and DB2 platform and version would be helpful..

Comment: db2 10.5 on RHEL 6
sample data for table1 (1,name1,addr1,type1),
                       (2,name2,addr2,type2)
                       (3,name3,addr3,type3)  
for table2 (1,noChange,high,true)
           (1,change,high,false)
           (2,change,low,false)

Comment: How about the error code you are getting?